# Grails web application loses connection to postgres database, what could be causing this?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, database

I am running **Postgres** on a Ubuntu instance with Tomcat as my application server. Suddenly my deployed applications are no longer connecting to their respective database. Looking at the logs `catalina.out` I get :

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Logging into my system and updating the password back to its original password fixes the problem but only for a short period of time.

```
alter user postgres with password 'new password';
```

Like I said, the password update fixes the problem for a short period of time. What could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is your system controlled by some management tool like puppet or chef (or other)?

Comment: No it isn't. I updated my system password, maybe someone was poking around?

Comment: Hard to tell, do you see anything suspicious in `last` output? Or is it known that several people are working on the same machine? Have you checked cronjobs etc. for anything related to this?